# Spring Boot Kotlin Mockito @MockBean dependency throws IllegalStateException null on method call

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, testing, junit, mockito

I am relatively new to Spring and Kotlin. I ran into this problem and it does not seem that there is a comprehensible (for me) explanation anywhere on the Internet.

This is the Controller and its method under test:

```
import com.xxx.data_api.entities.User
import com.xxx.data_api.repositories.UserRepository
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
class UserController(var userRepository: UserRepository) {

    @PostMapping("/users")
    fun create(@RequestBody user: User): User {
        return userRepository.save(user)
    }
}
```

This is the repository being injected:

```
import com.xxx.data_api.entities.User
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    fun findByEmail(email: String): User?
}
```

This is my test class:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.xxx.data_api.entities.User
import com.xxx.data_api.repositories.UserRepository
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Test
    fun createUserTest() {
        var user = User(null, "test@test.de", "test", "test", null, null)
        var gson = Gson()
        var jsonString = gson.toJson(user)

        Mockito.`when`(userRepository.save(user)).thenReturn(user);
       
        mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(jsonString)
        ).andExpect(status().isOk)
    }
}
```

There goes the exception:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: userRepository.save(user) must not be null
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: userRepository.save(user) must not be null
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:183)
    at com.xxx.data_api.integration.UserControllerTest.hello(UserControllerTest.kt:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:413)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: userRepository.save(user) must not be null
    at com.xxx.data_api.UserController.create(UserController.kt:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    ... 106 more
```

The mocked repository should be in the context and its **save** method is stubbed as you can see in the debugger:

[Debugger sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gdF0.png)

I probably miss a small important detail as always..
Any ideas are well appreciated!!

Comment: Even if it has nothing to do with the question: I would advise switching to Mockk right away. https://mockk.io/ And there is a Spring Adapter to use it: https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably haven't implemented `toEqual` and `hashCode` methods in `User` class; the default implementation will check for reference equality, which will never succeed, as the constructed `User` object in `UserController` will always have a different reference than the one you provided with `Mockito.when`.

Try implement `toEqual` and `hashCode` methods or just mark your class with `data` keyword and let the kotlin compiler do it of you.

Away from the actual question, I would like to suggest some "improvements" to your test snippet that you might not be aware of.

1. You don't need to mark a test class with `@ExtendWith` annotation, it's already imported for you with `@SpringBootTest` annotation.
2. Instead of using `Gson`, you may consider `ObjectMapper` class from Jackson, which's provided for you with `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class UserControllerTest {

    ..

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mapper: ObjectMapper

    @Test
    fun createUserTest() {

        ..

        val user = User( .. )
        val jsonString: String = mapper.writeValueAsString(user)
    }
}
```

3. Instead of using the traditional Mockito **when..then** in which you have to backticks every `when` method in Kotlin, you can alternatively user the behavior-driven variation **given..will**.

```java
// instead of
Mockito.`when`(userRepository.save(user)).thenReturn(user);

// you may use the alternative form 
BDDMockito.given(userRepository.save(user)).willReturn(user);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. 

_"Try implement toEqual and hashCode methods or just mark your class with data keyword and let the Kotlin compiler do it of you."_ I also thought that a data class would be useful here, but Spring seems to expects a _normal_ class to be used with its `@Entitiy` annotation.

Comment: No that wasn't it. I used the approach that I marked as the solution.

Comment: @adama8x Well, the solution above is not what you want; verify the content of the response with `andExpect(content().json(jsonString))` and it should fail this time because the mocked repository is still returning null.

Comment: @adama8x "Spring seems to expects a normal class to be used", I use `data` keyword on most of my entities, and I don't have any problem with that!

Comment: You where right, I was wrong. Just using a data class did solve the problem too and seems like the proper way doing it.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching and testing, I found out that the error is thrown by Kotlin, not the framework because of the nullable and non-nullable type conversion between Java and Kotlin types. So making the return type of the controller method `User?` solves the issue; this works:

```kotlin
@PostMapping("/users")
fun create(@RequestBody user: User): User? {
        return userRepository.save(user)
    }
```

However, that is not correct because `CrudRepository#save(T)` method never returns `null` values. I believe that when the conversion happens, Kotlin compiler automatically converts `T` into `T?`, and since your controller only returns `User` which is a non-nullable type, trying to return a nullable value from the repository causes the error: "...must not be null". Therefore adding the method signature to the repository solves the issue:

```java
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    fun save(user: User): User
}
```

Reference: [Spring Data JPA Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.nullability.kotlin)